# GetJSON's data : clarification needed

Tags: javascript, jquery, getjson

**Given JSON containing:**

```
[
{"myKey":"A","status":0,"score":1.5},{"myKey":"C","status":1,"score":2},
{"myKey":"D","status":0,"score":0.2},{"myKey":"E","status":1,"score":16},
{"myKey":"F","status":0,"score":0.4},{"myKey":"G","status":1,"score":3}
]
```

**Given JS such:**

```
MyJSON = $.getJSON('http://d.codio.com/hugolpz/getJson--/App/data/statusStarter2.json' );
```

**How to get the JSON's content (stringified) into localStorage.data ?**

**Note:** `localStorage.data = JSON.stringify(MyJSON);` returns `{"readyState":1}`, which is not my wish. I looked into [jQuery.getJSON/](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/), but I'am quite confused by the `function (data)`.

Comment: the `function(data)` is an anonymous callback function that gets called when the json has been retrieved, and will contain your data in the variable `data` or whatever you call the parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getJSON` works asynchronously and what it returns is AJAX request object. So use success callback function of `getJSON` to recieve the data

```
$.getJSON('http://d.codio.com/hugolpz/getJson--/App/data/statusStarter2.json', function(data) {
  // do JSON.stringify(data) here
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you try :

```
localStorage.setItem('data', JSON.stringify(MyJSON));
```

and

```
var JSON = localStorage.getItem('data');
```

and as ajax is async :

```
$.getJSON('url', function(MyJSON) {
     localStorage.setItem('data', JSON.stringify(MyJSON));
});
```