# Meteor: How to get JSON from facebook URL

Tags: facebook-graph-api, meteor

I am trying to get the users' birthday via

```
$.getJSON("https:graph.facebook.com/me?fields=birthday&access_token="+accessToken, function(data) {
    });
```

But unfortunately I have no idea on how to get the birthday itself because it gives me back this huge Object were I don't know how to handle it:
[image]

Could anyone please help me. I was looking at similar questions but unfortunately making the $.getJSON synchronous as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31129/how-can-i-return-a-variable-from-a-getjson-function) is deprecated. The questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17391324/getjsons-data-clarification-needed) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12460378/how-to-get-json-from-url-in-javascript) did not really help either. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the birthday in your code, you need navigate into Objects of your JSON data.

```
`$.getJSON("https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=birthday&access_token="+accessToken, function(data) {
    var birthday = data.birthday // This is your birthday
    var id = data.id // This is your Fb ID

    console.log('Hi! '+ id +'. Your birthday is '+ birthday)
});`
```

Comment: oh that is easier than I thought. Thank you so much @Rui Costa